# Google apps script: Form Submit trigger doesn't execute script properly, and script only works with a manual execution

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, form-submit

My script is supposed to send emails triggered by Form Submission. However, every time there's a new form submission, emails are sent using the previous submission and not the most recent.

When I execute it manually (click "run" in editor manually), the script then does what it's supposed to do : send an email using only the new form submission info (NOT the previous submission).

Any ideas on what to do?

```html
  function checkPurpose()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Mostrecent").getRange('C3');
  var purpose = sheet.getValue();
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    lock.waitLock(2000);
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
    lock.releaseLock();

  
  if (purpose === "Agent Information Change"){
    var agentSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Agentinfo");
    var a = agentSheet.getLastRow();
    for (var b = 2; b < a + 1; b++ ) {
        var emailAddress = agentSheet.getRange(b,1).getValue();
        var subject = agentSheet.getRange(b,2).getValue();
        var message = agentSheet.getRange(b,3).getValue();
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

     }
  }
   else if (purpose === "Manager Information Change"){
     var managerSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Managerinfo");
     var x = managerSheet.getLastRow();
     for (var y = 2; y < x + 1 ; y++) {
       var emailAddress2 = managerSheet.getRange(y,1).getValue();
       var subject2 = managerSheet.getRange(y,2).getValue();
       var message2 = managerSheet.getRange(y,3).getValue();
   
   

     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress2, subject2, message2);
    
   }
   }

 else if (purpose === "Agent Onboard"){
    var onboardSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Agentonboard");  
    var n = onboardSheet.getLastRow();
    for (var i = 2; i < n + 1 ; i++ ) {

    var emailAddress3 = onboardSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
    var subject3 = onboardSheet.getRange(i,5).getValue();
    var message3 = onboardSheet.getRange(i,6).getValue();
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress3, subject3, message3);
    
  }
 
 }
   }
```

Comment: Please explain how you setup your trigger.  It does not sound like you are using an onFormSubmit trigger as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Do you by any chance have the old version of the same function `checkPurpose` in the file or in another page in the script editor?

Comment: If you are using `onFormSubmit`, I recommend you use the [formResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) instead to actually process the response that triggered the function. Any reason you are using the sheet's data instead of `formResponse`?

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for the input. I meant that I had used the installable form submit trigger, so it doesn't show up in the script above.

Comment: @TheWizEd Good question but no I don't have another version.

Comment: Try unistalling the trigger and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. I had another function (autoSort) in a different script, which automatically sorts Form responses on the Google Sheet by the most recent date of submission. The problem was happening because the email function (checkPurpose) I was using was still being executed too fast before the Form responses could be sorted. Hence, I made the lock function have a longer time, so the sort function can put the new value at the top of the pile to be read in time.

Instead of:

```html
lock.waitLock(2000);
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
    lock.releaseLock()
```

I used:

```html
lock.waitLock(10000);
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    lock.releaseLock()
```

Comment: Honestly, this could work but you might encounter an issue later on. This is the issue with using spreadsheet data for `onFormSubmit`. That's why it is recommended to use `FormResponse` when dealing with these kinds of issues.